# Show that $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a metric on $X$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and let $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying:

$d(x,y) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y$, and

$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z)$, for all $x,y,z \in X$.

Attempt starts here:

Obviously I need to prove the properties of a metric, i.e.

$\text{(i)}\ d(x,y)\geq 0 \ \text{for all} \  x,y \in X$

$\text{(ii)}\ d(x,y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x = y$

$\text{(iii)}\ d(x,y) = d(y,x)\ \text{for all} \  x,y \in X$

$\text{(iv)}\ d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)\  \text{for} \ x,y,z \in X$

Obviously, (ii) is defined above, and I can get (iv) from the second line above by swapping $y$ and $z$ and applying (iii) after I've proved it, i.e.

$d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(z,y) = d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

My problem is proving (i) and (iii), since I'm not given an actual formula for the function.  Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Taking $x=y$: $d(x,x)\le d(x,z) + d(y,z)=2\cdot d(x,z)$, and $d(x,z)\ge 0$ follows. 
3) Taking $z=x$: $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(y,z)=d(x,x)+d(y,x)=d(y,x)$, and so $d(x,y)\le d(y,x)$. The other direction follows similarly.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.